# WP functions in .js

Tags: php, javascript

I have a huge `main.js` which includes 99% of my `JS` + plugins' `JS`. While loading time is a little bit longer when user visits the site for the first time, it gets cached and there will not be any other `.js` to load on other pages.

This creates a problem: I often find myself in situations where I need to use WordPress functions or general PHP in my `.js`.

I could name my `main.js` to `main.php` but then it doesn't get cached *(by default at least)* and it would spend unnessesary server resorces to process this *(one of my biggest - currently ~400KB)* file.

---

Does anyone have a good strategy how to use WordPress functions inside `.js` file?

Comment: Why not use a separate JS file for WP Functions and don't cache it?

Comment: That's kind of my question: how could I use functions inside `.js` file? I prefer to avoid `<script>` tags in my `.php` files.

Comment: You can use wp_localize_script() - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script If I am understanding correctly the question.

Comment: To use WP functions from JS look into AJAX calls https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action) in combination with wp_localize_script.

Comment: @jgraup Is there such thing as too much AJAX? I'm already using AJAX in quite a few places, if several AJAX are requested at same time for example, do they execute at once or there's a queue?

Comment: I think it's up to your sever to handle them -- so that's a server load question. Just be smart about your calls and cache in JS if you can. Otherwise... don't worry about it ~~ I'm not an AJAX expert by any means ~~

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso -- built using AJAX magic

Comment: Thanks @jgraup , I guess I will be satisfied with that answer and look more into it `wp_localize_script()` - I need to make few strings translatable in my `.js` one way or another. Write an answer so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access server-side functions you'll need to trigger a server event from JS using [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)), [JSON API](http://v2.wp-api.org), [XML/RPC](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support), [custom endpoints](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), or even [template_redirect hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect). Just be sure to liberally sprinkle [nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) when performing major functions.

---

The simple and proven technique is the [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) call. Setup a couple handlers when AJAX receives an `action` while the user is either logged-in or out  (nopriv).

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );

function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response
}
```

Then trigger the action via JS. The response is whatever you output in the handler but usually [wp_send_json_success](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success) will work fine.

```
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'add_foobar',
        'data':   'foobarid'
    }, 
    function(response){
        alert('The server responded: ' + response);
    }
);
```

---

If the JS needs access to server variables at runtime consider using [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) for more than text translations. It's really your opportunity to pass inline JS before a script loads. Thus ensuring JS has access to proper URLS, settings and states required for your app. `ajaxurl` may exist for some people but localizing that onto a variable will assure you that it's the correct url.

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

---

The [JSON API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) is also a good choice and very easy to setup. The major drawback is that it's only a few weeks old in core (since 4.4) and not fully established (full by 4.5). If you don't mind living on the edge you can be up and running in a short time with [custom endpoints](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/).

```
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'author' => $data['id'],
    ) );

    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    return $posts[0]->post_title;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ) );
} );
```

---

[XML RPC](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) was cool enough that everyone is switching to the JSON API if they can help it. It's a proven solution but who wants XML these days?

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_methods', function ($methods) {
    $methods['myNamespace.getTotalImageCount'] = 'rpc_myNamespace_getTotalImageCount';
    return $methods;
});

function rpc_myNamespace_getTotalImageCount($args)
{
    return array_sum((array)wp_count_attachments('image'));
}

add_action('parse_request', function () {

    // PULL USER CREDS FROM CURRENT USER
    global $current_user;

    $user = $current_user->user_login;
    $password = $user->data->user_pass;

    include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php');
    include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-http-ixr-client.php');
    $xmlrpc_url = home_url('xmlrpc.php');
    $client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_CLIENT($xmlrpc_url);

    // CALL OUR CUSTOM METHOD
    $response = $client->query('myNamespace.getTotalImageCount', array(0, $user, $password));

    echo 'Response:<pre>';
    $count = $client->message->params[0];
    print_r("{$count} total images");
    echo '</pre>';

    wp_die('FIN');
});
```

---

If you're curious about how much AJAX you should use then look no further than the future of WordPress.com's pet project [Calypso](https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso) where they redefine the admin back-end using as much JS as possible.

---

All these options are great unless someone turns off JS so keep that in mind when you construct your site.

---

There are also a few tools to help out along the way.

[Postman - REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) extension for Chrome can test GET and POST requests - [DEMO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPLlkhhRMvQ).

[Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) WP plugin can double check your custom [rewrite endpoints](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) are working correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this extremely thorough answer. I've done plenty of AJAX so far _(huge 100% ajax search feature with multiple WP_Queries + smaller things like voting etc)_, I think I'll stick with that. About turning off JS.. It's almost 2016 and my target audience is pretty tech-savvy with newer tech - I think I'll just show blank page with few notices if visitor have JS disabled..

Comment: If a person disables JS then they pretty much hate the internet anyway...